# Unknown NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a simple class to simulate an airplane reservation system. Unfortunately, I keep having my plan-to-hog-all-first-class-seats glee interrupted by multiple null pointer exceptions, and I can't find them anywhere. Here is my completed work:

```
import java.util.*;
public class airplane
{
    boolean[] seats;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public airplane(int num_of_seats)
    {
        boolean[] seats = new boolean[num_of_seats];
        for (int counter = 0; counter < num_of_seats; counter++)
        {
            seats[counter] = true;
        }
    }
    public boolean seatFirstClass(int seat)
    {
        if ( seat <= seats.length / 4 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public void seatsReserveFirstClass()
    {
        for (int seat = 0; seat < seats.length; seat++)
        {
            if (seats[seat] == true && seat <= seats.length / 4)
            {
                seats[seat] = false;
                System.out.print("I have reserved one seat in first class. Please tell the passenger to enjoy their flight with these airlines! ");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("I could not find a seat in first class. Can the passenger switch to economy? (0 for no, 1 for yes) ");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        if (choice == 0)
            System.out.print("I could not add passenger due to lack of a seat.");
        else if (choice == 1)
        {
            this.seatsReserveEconomy();
        }
    }
    public void seatsReserveEconomy()
    {
        for (int seat = 0; seat < seats.length; seat++)
        {
            if (seats[seat] == true && seat > seats.length / 4)
            {
                seats[seat] = false;
                System.out.print("I have reserved a seat in economy. Please tell the passenger to enjoy their flight with these airlines! ");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("I could not find a seat in economy. Can the passenger switch to first class? (0 for no, 1 for yes) ");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        if (choice == 0)
            System.out.print("I could not add the passenger due to a lack of seats.");
        else if (choice == 1)
            this.seatsReserveFirstClass();
    }
    public void planeClear()
    {
        for (int seat = 0; seat < seats.length; seat++)
        {
            seats[seat] = true;
        }
    }
    public void seatUnReserve(int seat)
    {
        if (seat < seats.length)
        {
            if (seats[seat] == false)
            {
                seats[seat] = true;
                System.out.printf("Seat %d has been unreserved.\n", seat);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("The seat you have entered is already unreserved.\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("There is no seat number %d on this plane.\n", seat);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a main class to test it:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean check = false;
        System.out.print("How many seats does the plane have? ");
        int num_of_seats = scan.nextInt();
        airplane Airplane = new airplane(num_of_seats);
        while (check == false)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter 0 to reserve a first class seat, 1 to reserve an economy seat,\n2 to cancel a reservation, 3 to clear the plane,\nand 4 to quit the program. ");
            int choice = scan.nextInt();
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 0:
               Airplane.seatsReserveFirstClass();
               break;
            case 1:
                Airplane.seatsReserveEconomy();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("Which seat should I unreserve? ");
                int seat = scan.nextInt();
                Airplane.seatUnReserve(seat);
                break;
            case 3:
                Airplane.planeClear();
                break;
            case 4:
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If this is run, the dreaded NullPointException error shows up, and I'm not sure what calls this beast.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at airplane.seatsReserveFirstClass(airplane.java:22)
at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

Comment: `"...the dreaded NullPointException error shows up, and I'm not sure what calls this beast."` -- The Exception stackTrace will tell you! Where is your stacktrace, and which line does it tell you throws the NPE? Don't ignore the exception messages -- study them!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at airplane.seatsReserveFirstClass(airplane.java:63)
         at test.main(test.java:58)

Comment: So what line is airplane.java 63? Again, these messages tell you enough information to look for a solution, although likely your answer is below in Hernan's answer. The key though is not to ignore the exception stacktrace messages for they are key. Also please learn to use Java naming conventions if you want to help others understand your code.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I didn't know that (brand new to java). Thanks, that's good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a field member:

boolean[] seats;

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public airplane(int num_of_seats)
{
```

here you shadow the field member with a local variable, you are not touching the other one

```
    boolean[] seats = new boolean[num_of_seats];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < num_of_seats; counter++)
    {
        seats[counter] = true;
    }
}
```

it should look like this:

```
public airplane(int num_of_seats)
{
    seats = new boolean[num_of_seats];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < num_of_seats; counter++)
    {
        seats[counter] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Herman's quick eye found answer for you allready!! Anyway I extend the help for future...

You can use Java IDE , eclipse is good one, to develop programs. One of the very important feature, I believe, is debugging, which enables you to completely control your application  and trace exception quickly.

Here is quick tutorial how to debug an application from eclipse ( Refer 4.3 for Exception breakpoints)

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html